# codenameone is there a simpler/nicer way to call a Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, codenameone

Every time my mobile app needs to access the DB, I have to write this piece of code.

```
//NetworkManager.getInstance().start();
        ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest();
        request.setUrl(WebConstants.HOST+"URL");
        request.setPost(false);
        request.addArgument("x",y);
        request.addResponseListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                NetworkEvent event = (NetworkEvent)evt;
                Exception error = event.getError();
                if(error != null) {
                    return;
                }
                ConnectionRequest request = event.getConnectionRequest();
                byte[] result = request.getResponseData();

                String response = new String(result);

                /** Process the string response **/

            }
        });
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
```

This becomes really tedious when the web app constantly accesses the DB and for every call I need to copy, paste and modify same code. I tried to create a method and return the string response, but since the web service is done asynchronously, the method that calls the web service has to finish before web service method process the response. Therefore, I can't simplified this part of code. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the code in

`/** Process the string response **/`

into a `Callable`, then you can create a generic method that calls

`callable.call()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addToQueueAndWait(request)` which blocks until the network operation completes and is completely safe to use on the EDT since it uses [invoke and block](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/callserially-the-edt-invokeandblock-part-2).

You can also use something like the [webservice wizard](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-remote-webservices-perform-operations-on-the-server.html) which encapsulates web calls in method calls.

Comment: thanks, Shai. I had used the webservice wizard and makes code more robust and usable.

Comment: You need to invoke the show dialog method then dispose that dialog after.